# I cant resolve android file download issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to donload a file from the intenet. I am able to download multiple files one after another. when one donload completes I start the next one by building a new connection and repeating all the steps for the first download. So I think that I possibly have multiple connections open at the same time.

The problem is that after donloading 3 or 4 files the next file is not downloaded.
I am hopeful that there is a better approach of using the existing connection for further downloads or of destroying existing connection before creating a new one. Here is my code for the downloader class:

```
public class Downloader {

private OnDownloadCompleteListener onDownloadCompleteListener;

public void startDownload(String url){
    new DownloadTask().execute(url);
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {   return downloadURL(params[0]);  } catch (IOException e) {   return "cantDownload"; }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        onDownloadCompleteListener.onDownloadComplete(result);
    }
}

private String downloadURL(String targetURL) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    URL url;

    try{
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP , new InetSocketAddress( "192.168.100.13" , 8080));
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 );
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 );
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        String line = null;
        StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){  tmp.append(line);   }
        line = String.valueOf(tmp);
        return line ;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

public void setOnDownloadCompleteListener(OnDownloadCompleteListener onDownloadCompleteListener){
    this.onDownloadCompleteListener = onDownloadCompleteListener;
}
public interface OnDownloadCompleteListener{
    public void onDownloadComplete(String downloadedHTML);
}
}
```

To start a download I call the method startDownload(url) from the main class.
when this download is complete I again call the method startDownload so basically everything is repeated. 
what is a better way to do this?

Comment: what happens when u download the 3 rd or 4th file? Do you get any error?

Comment: The documentation for AsyncTask suggest doing something like `execute(url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,etc..);`` Have you tried following the instructions there? http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this class before, but following the instructions I think something like this will work. Basically, the difference is startDownload handles all the urls at the same time. For a related example see, the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation.

```
public void startDownload(String... urls) {
    new DownloadTask().execute(urls)
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {   return downloadURL(params);  } catch (IOException e) {   return "cantDownload"; }
    }
    private String[] downloadURL(String... targetURLs) throws IOException {
            String[] lines = new String[targetURLS.length];
            for(int i = 0;i<targetURLs.length;i++) {
             try{
    url = new URL(targetURL);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP , new InetSocketAddress( "192.168.100.13" , 8080));
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 );
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 );
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    int response = conn.getResponseCode();
    String line = null;
    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){  tmp.append(line);   }
    line = String.valueOf(tmp);
    lines[i] = line;
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        is.close();
    }
}
          return lines; 
            }

}
```

}

Comment: what if i dont want to execute bulk url, just want to download file one by one by clicking url (or button) shown on screen

Comment: Then you need to make a new AsyncTask every time, because the documentation says execute can only be called once.